# problem in geometry_msgs::Pose

Tags: ros, pose, geometry-msgs, quaternion

[image: Rosanswers logo]

what is x, y, z and w in Quaternion oriention?
specially what is w?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30340/problem-in-geometry_msgs::pose/) by [navidnabavi](https://answers.ros.org/users/1990/navidnabavi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2012-03-23

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have a look at [REP103](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0103.html) on Standard Units of Measure and Coordinate Conventions. If you're not familiar with quaternions it also helps to have a look at pages like [this Wikipedia page on Quaternions and spatial rotation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2012-03-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 9

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tully](https://answers.ros.org/users/7/tully/) on 2012-03-23**:
Also for information about any message you can use the rosmsg command with the --raw option to see the comments. Or browse the online docs for the message http://ros.org/doc/electric/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/Pose.html

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

For representing orientation in ROS, quaternions are used. They do not represent a human-readable format like e.g. euler angles (more information about quaternions here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion ).

To easily convert between euler angles and quaternions, the tf-ROS package offers a set of functions like "createQuaternionFromYaw" or similar...

Have a look at <tf/transform_datatypes.h> for more information.

---

Originally posted by [michikarg](https://answers.ros.org/users/1314/michikarg/) with karma: 2108 on 2012-03-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2